# Confused about about how to iterate this collection

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

What I want to do is get all available network adapters 
with key and value pairs.So I have class named Adapters consist of two variable first one is to keep
 registry key and the second one is to
 keep Adapter name such as (wireless ,local area and so on).And  this is my code

```
  List<Adapters> GetAdapterNames(string regPath)
      {
          List<Adapters> list = new List<Adapters>();


          RegistryKey key = RootNode(regPath, false);
          if (key != null)
          {
              string[] par = key.GetSubKeyNames();

              foreach (string node in par)
              {

                  if (node != "Descriptions")
                  {

                      RegistryKey keys = RootNode(regPath+"\\"+node + "\\Connection", false);
                      string name = keys.GetValue("Name").ToString();

                      list.Add(new Adapters(name,node));


                  }

      }
     return list;
```

And this is my adapterclass

```
class Adapters
{
    private string _name;
    private string _val;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public string Val
    {
        get { return _val; }
        set { _val = value; }
    }

    public Adapters(string name,string value)
    {
        _name = name;
        _val = value;
    }
}
```

The problem is how can I give this list to the combobax    and  loop through in it .
something like this

```
 private const string ADAPTER_PATH =
            @"SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Network\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         List<Adapters>adapters= GetAdapterNames(ADAPTER_PATH);


           combobax.valueMember=//list.name
 combobax.displayMember=list.node;


        }
```

Comment: Which ComboBox?  WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET?

Comment: Just winforms friend

Comment: Have a good look at how/why we use Tags for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example you've got (please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for advice on how to provide a good code example in your question), the following would work:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Adapters>adapters= GetAdapterNames(ADAPTER_PATH);

    combobax.DataSource = adapters;
    combobax.ValueMember = "Name";
    combobax.DisplayMember = "Val";
}
```

You can assign any implementation of `IList` to the `DataSource` property of the `ComboBox`.

The `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties can be used to control what value is returned from the `SelectedValue` property and what string is displayed in the `ComboBox` itself, respectively. They are `string` values which contain the name of a property of the class of the objects used to populate the `ComboBox`.

Notes:

- I have no idea if `combobax` is in fact the correct name for the field in your form that contains the reference to the `ComboBox` object. That's what you typed, so it's what I've left here.
- It seems a little odd to display the node registry key name, and use the "friendly" adapter name as the value member. But again, that's what you typed, so that's what I've shown in the example.